# Function of batch in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, mathematical-optimization

I am new to TensorFlow and Machine Learning and found the concept of batch.

What is the purpose of splitting the DataSets into batches and how does the TensorFlow perform an optimization task on variables, using different sub-sets?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing a few things, as far as I understand.

First, you need to split the dataset into two (or more) distinct sets. The one is a set that you train your system on, and the second one is used to test your model.

This are basics of ML and you should easily find more in the internet. Look for "cross-validation" or "train, validation, test sets".

Batch is something that is usually important in Neural Networks (NN). You are not using one example at each training step (then the algorithm would be called Stochastic Gradient Descent), nor every example at each training step (this would be Batch Gradient Descent). Usually, it is the best to train NN using mini-batches (Mini-batch Gradient Descent).

It is a trade-off in optimization between accuracy and training speed.

Tensorflow is just a library for NN. You can easily find how sets and batches are split in many tutorials. Remember to learn the basic concepts first, for example in this great class:
https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of splitting the DataSet into batches is typically to speed up the learning. Instead of processing the entire set of training examples, it processes only a batch, which is just a small subset of the entire training set, at a time. There are various techniques about how to formulate such batches and process them to get the final trained model.